Are there any community tools that automatically configure log shipping from Amazon S3?
There are many community tools for setting up log shipping, e.g. dbatools' Invoke-DbaDbLogShipping. However, they assume that both the source and target server have access to a shared network share.
In my situation, the only shared storage between my target and source servers (both Amazon EC2s) is an Amazon S3 bucket. Are there any community tools setting up log shipping allows for Amazon S3 to be the shared storage? I could roll my own without much trouble, but I struggle to believe that this isn't a solved problem. Either I'm missing something big or this should be a frequently faced problem among SQL Server users on Amazon EC2.

The three close votes suggest that I am indeed missing something big. Is there an easy way to share storage between EC2s that is friendly to log shipping and doesn't involve S3?

The (now four) close votes (mine included) are because this is a shopping list question. “Are there any community tools setting up log shipping allows for Amazon S3 to be the shared storage?” If your actual question is if there’s an easy way to do this, you may want to delete this one and start fresh.

I created a log shipping tool that can do this.  If you are on SQL 2022, you can backup directly to S3 and use the tool I created to restore directly from S3.
I initially created the tool to solve two problems:

Log shipping at scale with 1000s of DBs. From a UNC path.
Log shipping direct from Azure blob

I added S3 support from version 1.7.0.  The tool is free and open source - MIT license like dbatools.
To get started, download the latest version from the Releases section and use the wiki.
If you are on a version older than SQL 2022, using a file gateway is a good option.  This allows you to access the files in your S3 bucket via a UNC path with a local cache.
Hope this helps
